# Script to list passwords for wifi connections

Tags: wireless, password

I am writing a script that finds various pieces of information about the ethernet interfaces. I have got most using `ifconfig` and `iwconfig`. However I now need to extract the passwords. The passwords seem to be located in files that are named after the SSID in files like this:

`/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<mySsid>`

However I imagine you cannot rely on the file name  always being exactly equal to the SSID (correct me if I'm wrong).

Is there an alternative? I.e. a command or something that will extract the password given `wlan0` etc.

ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

> However I imagine you cannot rely on the file name always being exactly equal to the SSID (correct me if I'm wrong).

Correct.

If you look inside the files you will see that there is an ID:

```
[connection]
id=Schijfwereld
```

This is what the file identifies and matches the SSID inside the file:

```
[802-11-wireless]
ssid=Schijfwereld
mode=infrastructure
```

> The passwords seem to be located in files that are named after the SSID in files like this:

The system-connections directory holds all your WIFI networks that are ticked **available to all users**, with the PSK in cleartext. The lines will have `psk=` and the password behind it. If "available to all users" is NOT set the password is not saved in the system-connections directory.